# How to know if a user has more than one browser tab opened with my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to know this only using Javascript? I'm trying to achieve something similar to Gmail's chat connected users list. If the user has more than one tab and then closes one, the closed tab doesn't affect the "connected" state of the user and still shows him/her in the chat list.

Comment: I guess this might be somehow possible by giving each window a random name when it's not set... Maybe somebody can provide an implementation. What do you need this for though? Maybe there's a better way to do what you need

Comment: how can i give a name to a window?

Comment: [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use server side technologies to have a cross browser experience that can detect the number of windows currently open for your site.

Basically you have to set it up like gmail and use ajax technologies to determine the activity/status of the current user and update it in a database.  The implementation will vary on the technologies you are using.

Comment: ok, i'm using django (python) in server side. the problem is that i don't know how to update the state when the user have more than one browser tabs. I know that i can use beforeUnload in javascript, but what happend when it has multiples tabs opened? :S

Comment: You would have to periodically ping the sever to update the status of the user.  For example after the window has a setTimeout the pings the server every five seconds.  If a window fails to ping the server that it has closed.  BeforeUnload isn't always dependable, but can work(for example the ipad fails to call that event).

Answer (score 0):

Making use of (psuedo-)random names / identifiers onLoad, localStorage to keep a cross-tab / cross-window list of opened windows and beforeUnload to remove closed windows from the list would allow you to track how many windows are open. onFocus/onBlur would allow you to find out which one is currently active/inactive.